# How to publish RTSP stream from ip camera with gstreamer?

Tags: gstreamer, rtsp, publishing

I have a [rtsp-simple-server](https://github.com/aler9/rtsp-simple-server)  running on Debian and
I try to publish RTSP from my ip camera (h264 + pcm ulaw) to RTSP server with gstreamer.
I tried this command:

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.1.1:554/11 !
rtph264depay ! rtspclientsink location=rtsp://server.com:8554/camstream1 protocols=tcp
```

It works, but it streams video only. The following command streams audio only:

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.1.1:554/11 !
rtppcmudepay ! rtspclientsink location=rtsp://server.com:8554/camstream1 protocols=tcp
```

How can I stream video + audio?

Answer (score 3):

Try this (or something like this) :

gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.1.1:554/11 name=mysrc !
rtph264depay ! rtspclientsink location=rtsp://server.com:8554/camstream1 protocols=tcp mysrc. ! rtppcmudepay ! rtspclientsink location=rtsp://server.com:8554/camstream1 protocols=tcp

OR you might have to MUX the audio and video first, before sending to rtspclientsink (this part is beyond me)

Try this first on a PC to see if the first part works

gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.1.1:554/11 name=mysrc !
rtph264depay ! autovideosink mysrc. ! rtppcmudepay ! autoaudiosink